# Running code as a privileged user - managing password changes

Tags: c#, windows, deployment, service

I've been tasked with creating a small C# (.Net 4.0) console application that will run on a customer's Windows 2008R2 server. The application must "run as" a specific domain user, and also needs to be running as close to 24x7 as possible.

I can create a dual console application/Windows service, or I can use the excellent FireDaemon to run the console app as a service, and this covers the "must run all the time" aspect.

However, the customer's domain policy is to change passwords every 120 days - including the account that this application will run under. There's no possibility to excluding the account from this policy.

Therefore, it looks like we'll install the app (either as service or via FireDaemon), the password on the account will expire, and the next time the server reboots or the app restarts, the authentication will fail.

I'm used to having complete control of the deployment environment, and therefore I'm a bit stumped as to how to work around this. How can we ensure the application always runs as the privileged user?

(I'm aware this has at least one foot in [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com)'s remit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ...the password on the account will expire, and the next time the server reboots or the app restarts, the authentication will fail

This is what [Managed Service Accounts and Virtual Accounts](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd548356%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) are for. Since you target Windows Server 2008R2 and later, this option *is* available for you:

> **Managed service accounts** in Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows 7 are managed domain accounts that provide the following features to simplify service administration:
>
> - Automatic password management.
> - Simplified SPN management, including delegation of management to other administrators. Additional automatic SPN management is available at the Windows Server 2008 R2 domain functional level. For more information, see "Requirements for using managed service accounts and virtual accounts" in this document.
>
> **Virtual accounts** in Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows 7 are "managed local accounts" that provide the following features to simplify service administration:
>
> - No password management is required.
> - The ability to access the network with a computer identity in a domain environment.

Answer (score 0):

I think [named pipes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546085%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) could be of use here.

You can create your a service contract that includes a method for updating the password the program is using to authenticate. Have an external program accept the new password as input in whatever form of your choosing, then just pipe it over to the service. The method defined on the server from the service contract can take it, store it somewhere, and then you can force it to re-authenticate with the new password.